# How to wrap my native C library for C#?

Tags: c, pinvoke, clr, unmanaged, managed

I have a big native C library with a very large header file.

The header file contains 50 enums, 500 structs and 5 methods.

I once wrapped it for C# using P/Invoke, 50 enums were all copy paste, methods were a few, but it took a **vast amount of energy** for me to write the structures.

And when the library updates, I should check all the structures to see whether any data type has changed or not.

Once, I was told that using CLR is faster and more efficient. I was hoping to find a way I could convert the unmanaged enums and structures to managed. But as I tested, it seems that I have to make the structures in a managed style again and have their fields copied.

Is it true?

Is there any way to simplify the structure conversion?

Comment: It is called C++/CLI, it can read the .h file.  SWIG should probably be mentioned, although it is the kind of tool that solves one problem and produces two new ones.  You'll just have to consider to make the interface thinner, 500 structs is complete redrum.  Something more dynamic like xml or json would probably be wise.

Comment: @HansPassant The library has been given to me by my company. I can not change anything about it.

Comment: It is not clear why you think you need to change it.  Point is to make the C# interface less painful so you don't have to repeat all those structure declarations.

Answer (score 1):

With [CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp) from the Mono Project you can easily and quickly generate .NET bindings from C/C++ header files of native code.

A complete documentation can be found here: https://github.com/mono/CppSharp/blob/master/docs/GeneratingBindings.md